# Abort Called-corrupted size vs. prev_size error in c

Tags: c, malloc

In HackerRank's Array Reversal problem,I wrote a code like below and it works fine with these test cases:
n=7

1 13 15 20 12 13 2

But for only one test case it didn't work and gave me the error message I wrote in the title.(For this):
n=6

16 13 7 2 1 12

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int *array = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(n));
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    scanf("%d",array+i);
for(int ncpy=n; ncpy>0; ncpy--)
    printf("%d ",*(array+ncpy));
printf("\n");
free(array);   
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)` ==> `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`

Comment: `for(int ncpy=n; ncpy>0; ncpy--)` ==> `for(int ncpy=n-1; ncpy>=0; ncpy--)`

Comment: In C arrays are indexed from `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane My old version was like you wrote but it didn't work,too.So I tried this.

Comment: If so why it is okey for other test cases?You can try on your own compiler,it works for linux but for only input 6 it didn't work on hackerrank @WeatherVane

Comment: What about the final trailing space, will that fail? What about the range of possible inputs, are they in `int` range?

Comment: `If so why it is okey for other test cases?` Because it is undefined behavior which can make things seem to work perfectly, until they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indices in C start at 0, so for an array of size `n` the indices are 0 to `n-1`, not 1 to `n`.  This means you're reading / writing past the end of the array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and causing a crash.

Change your loops to go from 0 to n-1 instead of 1 to n

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%d",array+i);
for(int ncpy=n-1; ncpy>=0; ncpy--)
    printf("%d ",*(array+ncpy));
```

Comment: @nicholai_hel Arrays start at 0, so the 1st term has index 0, up to the 6th term which has index 5.

Comment: Yeah it works!But my code works smoothly for many test cases,too.It gave this error for only one of the tests.Why it worked if it's wrong :D

Comment: @nicholai_hel One of the ways undefined behavior can manifest itself is that things sometimes work properlyand sometimes don't.  A crash isn't guaranteed.